# Single reusable value for post meta: Custom Taxonomy or Post Meta?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, post-meta

Suppose I have a post meta like "Region" it will contain values like "Region 1", "Region 2" etc. But it should only contain ONE value. Also I would like it to have an archive page. If I use custom taxonomy, users can select more than 1 value. Is it possible to have a drop down type selection instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mutually exclusive values use post meta. It is faster to read than assigned taxonomies too.

It *is* possible to create your own interface:

1. Set the parameter `show_ui` to `false` when you register the taxonomy.
2. Register a meta box where you print out all existing taxons with radio boxes.
3. Add a save action to assign the value to the taxonomy.

But in most cases you’re doing something wrong and misuse the taxonomy. ;)

Comment: curious, why is meta faster? why would this be a misuse of the taxonomy? i've done something similar and have been wondering whether to use tax or meta.

Comment: @helgatheviking The query for taxonomies is rather complex: It asks three tables (`terms`, `term_relationships` and `term_taxonomy`) and is harder to optimize than the query for post meta which just asks `posts` and `post_meta`. **But** if your post meta contains serialized data it will be very slow of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these posts will help you achieve that :

- [Saving Taxonomy Terms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1794/need-help-in-saving-taxonomy-terms-85-solved-just-need-some-help)
- [WordPress Custom Taxonomy Input Panels](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-custom-taxonomy-input-panels)