# getting all values of a custom taxonomy if there is no post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am working on a real estate theme. I am using some custom taxonomies such as Listing Purpose and Property type etc. 
In my add Listing form I am displaying each taxonomy in a dropdown, for which to work accordingly, I need to manually select all the taxonomy values in a post first then I can see the dropdown being filled properly.
Today, for a check I deleted all the posts and came back to add Listing page and the dropdowns were empty.
My question is that is there any way that I need not to first select all the values in each taxonomy?

hope i was clear enough to get a suitable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to do it and it was quite simple and I was unable to figure out till now. Thanks to @NetConstructor.com in his reply to the post [Saving Taxonomy Terms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1794/need-help-in-saving-taxonomy-terms-85-solved-just-need-some-help) made me realize that using get_terms function (which I was already using), there is an argument 'hide_empty' helps to do the magic. How noob I am...

Thanks and hope it may help some others out there...