# Altering the appearance of custom taxonomy inputs

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm working on a site that will make use of a few custom taxonomies (for custom post types). I've chosen to make some of the taxonomies hierarchical because the method of inputting values (checking boxes) is more desirable for this site than the free-form input of non-hierarchical taxonomies. However, what I would **really** like is to be able to use radio button inputs instead of check boxes. Additionally, I'd like to remove the dropdown that is used to choose the parent item in the taxonomy.
[image: screenshot]

Am I going about this the wrong way? Should I start with non-hierarchical taxonomies and modify the input methods on those instead? I'm completely open to input and will gladly answer any questions or supply more information if I can.

Comment: +1 Good Question. This would also be nice for a project I'm working on too. Moreover, have the custom taxonomy be a dropdown menu instead of a list of "categories".

Comment: Yeah, a dropdown would be great as well.

Comment: These two seems to be dealing with very similar issue: [Custom Post Type - Taxonomy Dropdown Menu?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/custom-post-type-taxonomy-dropdown-menu) and [Need Help in Saving Taxonomy Terms](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1794/need-help-in-saving-taxonomy-terms-85-solved-just-need-some-help)

Comment: Rather than trying to modify the existing metabox, what you might look into doing is removing the default metabox for the given taxonomy, then registering your own to call a custom function that displays the terms in a radio group, and this would tie in with the two links provided above by maugly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure thing, just use CSS and the `'admin_head'` hook to make it disappear. I believe this is what you are looking for?

[image: Hierarchical taxonomy entry on WordPress post page without the parent]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20110122-020011.png))</sub>

Just add the following to your theme's `functions.php` file or to a `.php` file of a plugin that you might be writing. Note that I included an `'init'` hook to define the *"Home"* post type and the *"Bath"* taxonomy so others can more easily follow the example. Also note that if your taxonomy is named *Baths"* you'll need to change the CSS selector to be `#newbaths_parent` instead of `#newbath_parent`:

```
add_action('admin_head','remove_bath_parents');
function remove_bath_parents() {
  global $pagenow;
  if (in_array($pagenow,array('post-new.php','post.php'))) { // Only for the post add & edit pages
    $css=<<<STYLE
<style>
<!--
#newbath_parent {
  display:none;
}
-->
</style>
STYLE;
    echo $css;
  }
}
add_action('init','add_homes_and_baths');
function add_homes_and_baths() {
  register_post_type('home',
    array(
      'label'           => 'Homes',
      'public'          => true,
      'rewrite'         => array('slug' => 'homes'),
      'hierarchical'    => false,
    )
  );
  register_taxonomy('bath', 'home', array(
    'hierarchical'    => true,
    'label'           => 'Baths',
    'rewrite'         => array('slug' => 'baths' ),
    )
  );
}
```

### UPDATE

So it seems I missed **the radio button part** of the question. Unfortunately WordPress does not make this easy but you can make it happen by using [**PHP output buffering**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) *(via the `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` functions.)* Just find a hook before the metabox is output (`'add_meta_boxes'`) and a hook after it is output (`'dbx_post_sidebar'`) and then search the captured HTML for `'checkbox'` and replace with `'radio'`, echo it to the screen and yer done! Code follows:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes','mysite_add_meta_boxes',10,2);
function mysite_add_meta_boxes($post_type, $post) {
  ob_start();
}
add_action('dbx_post_sidebar','mysite_dbx_post_sidebar');
function mysite_dbx_post_sidebar() {
  $html = ob_get_clean();
  $html = str_replace('"checkbox"','"radio"',$html);
  echo $html;
}
```

And the evidence:

[image: Screenshot showing taxonomies using radio buttons]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20110123-043759.png))</sub>

Comment: "Look Ma, no parent field!" Mike, you got me laughing! :D

Comment: @maugly - That's my default. :D

Comment: @haha - Glad you like it. :)

Comment: Fantastic, as always.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand how this works... From reading the php docs, it appears that this essentially 'captures' all output after add_meta_boxes, then outputs it (changed with str_replace) after all the metaboxes are created. Is that somewhat accurate?

Comment: @tnorthcutt - That's exactly correct. This technique of output buffering is a nasty hack, but sometimes a nasty hack is the only option you have, as in this case unless you want to code your own metabox from scratch *(which frankly is also an option.)*

Comment: I suppose I may look at coding my own metabox... I would also like to alter the layout of the radio buttons (in a table rather than <ul>), but that doesn't look possible without redoing the box completely. I'm assuming I can figure out how to code my own by studying the relevant core files? Unless there's an easy how-to floating around out there for setting this up in a table, of course.

Comment: @tnorthcutt - Frankly, I'd recommend coding your own metabox. That's what I did and it's really not hard for this. Just do a view source and match `<input>` and `<select>` names and you won't even have to do anything to capture the taxonomy; WordPress will do it for you. OR, use a custom field and bypass taxonomy which might be overkill for this.

Comment: `Just find a hook before the metabox is output and a hook after it is output and then search the captured HTML and replace, echo it to the screen and yer done!`   Sounds good, but you make finding the appropriate hooks too easy. Is there some procedure that can help with this?

Comment: @Synetech Yes it can be hard, but [**with tools**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-wordpress-hooks/339#339) it is doable, and **[with really good tools**](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) it's almost trivial. If there is **ONE** thing I can recommend to would-be WordPress development experts it's to get **PhpStorm** and [set up XDEBUG or Zend Debugger](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/03/configure-php-debugging-in-phpstorm-2-0/); nothing else even comes close to helping someone understand what is going on under the hood in WordPress.

Comment: I’ve already tried Adam Brown’s site and ran into exactly the issues that you listed in your answer. I’m sure it’s great for common tasks like hooking posts and comments, but for less common, and less documented tasks like modifying the My Sites page, it doesn’t help much. Thanks for the tip about using a PHP debugger; until WordPress gets better, more thorough documentation, that may be the best bet.

Comment: @Synetech No amount of documentation will ever compare with tracing through the running code with a debugger. Don't think of a debugger as a _substitute_ for "poor" docs, think of it as the ultimate documentation that is wielded by the elite WP coders. Join the club!

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I’d love to. I’ve been debugging code (BAS, PAS, ASM, C/C++, etc.) for over 20 years, but that was with a traditional debugger and IDE. I guess I just haven’t wrapped my head around web-apps being debuggable “programs” in the same way as opposed to just scripts (then again, batch-files are scripts and I’ve debugged those as well…)

Comment: @Synetech Me too _(25+ years dev experience.)_ PhpStorm is an IDE and it's UX is very similar in concept to Visual Studio. Easiest way is to set up a local WP install; easy on Mac, a little harder on Win. It's a struggle to get it working the first time but the first time you see it stop on a breakpoint you get the feeling like its been raining for months and the clouds just parted to reveal glorious sunshine! :)

Answer (score 2):

or, if you're lazy can use this plugin: [Single Value Taxonomy UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/single-value-taxonomy-ui/)

*(I would've rather added this as a comment to Mike's answer as it mostly does the same thing - but I can't yet add comments)*

Comment: No update in 2 years unfortunately :( This is really something WP should add core support for as many people would use one-term-per-object taxonomies if it was an option (i.e. use taxonomies rather than meta when query performance is important).