# How to dynamically save a selected option from page "Templates" selectbox?

Tags: pages, templates, page-template, select

When I select a template for a page from the "Templates" selectbox, the selected item gets “value=selected” only after I hit save draft/publish/update.

`<option value='template-gallery.php'  selected='selected'>Gallery</option>`

How can the option receive the value “selected” without the need of save/publish/update hit button? (like on widgets page: they get saved without page refresh)

Thank you!

Comment: because on widgets page wordpress loads some javascript which handles the transfer via AJAX.

Comment: @MridulAggarwal I thought so...I`m wondering if there`s a jquery solution for this. I`ve seen selectboxes which enables other things when options are selected but I`m not sure if this can be made on wp admin selectboxes too. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have to be fully coded and tested, but I think the roadmap is:

#### Deregister the Default Meta Box and Make a Custom One

@MikeSchinkel answer to this question is very detailed and thoughtful: [Adding Page Attributes Metabox and Page Templates to the Posts Edit Page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/2765/12615)

In that case, it is for *duplicating* the Pages Template Meta Box into *Posts*.

This other Q&A ( [How To Change Custom Taxonomy To Radio Buttons](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/44026/12615) ) provides an example of *replacing* the Taxonomies Meta Box.

#### Add Ajax to the Custom Templates Meta Box

In [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54875/12615), there's an example of custom meta box that runs an Ajax call, that in turn makes a database query to modify an attachment parent.

To do the Page Template live switch, it would be a matter of modifying the table `wp_postmeta` where the current template value is stored.

The `meta_key` name is `_wp_page_template` and its value the template file name.

[image: results of query wp_postmeta _wp_page_template]

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. I`ll give it a try and see if is really working!

Comment: Nice, and if you build a working code please publish as an answer here :)