# Dropdown list of taxonomies won't display selected

Tags: custom-taxonomy, metabox

I used the answer in this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/custom-post-type-taxonomy-dropdown-menu) to show a dropdown list of my taxonomies and it works great.

But when I save the post/update and the page refreshes/loads the taxonomy I selected reverts back to the last taxonomy on the list. I checked the database and it does save the chosen taxonomy correctly so it's obviously how I echo the data right? How can I fix this so that it stays on the selected taxonomy?

```
$term = isset( $values['meta-box-events_select'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['meta-box-events_select'][0] ) : '';
```

THIS IS THE CODE I USED TO SHOW THE DROPDOWN

```
        <?php $tax = get_object_taxonomies('activities');
        $taxterms = get_terms( $tax, 'orderby=count&offset=1&hide_empty=0&fields=all' );
    ?>
    <select name='meta-box-events_select' id='meta-box-events_select'>
        <option value='' <?php if (!count( $names )) echo "selected";?>>Select Term</option>
        <?php 
        foreach ( $taxterms as $term ) { 
            echo '<option value="' . $term->slug . '" selected>' . $term->name . '</option>',"\n"; 
        } ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are adding the term 'selected' to each option - you only want it added to the currently chosen option.

You can use the WordPress built-in function, [`selected`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected), which allows you to compare two values (say the saved term's ID and the current options term ID) and when they match prints 'selected'.

For instance:

```
<?php
$current_term;//Retrieve the current saved term's;
//Get the current term's ID, or 0 if it doesn't exist
$current_term_id = ($current_term ? $current_term->term_id : 0); 
?>

<select name='meta-box-events_select' id='meta-box-events_select'>
 <option value='' <?php selected(0,$current_term_id)?>>Select Term</option>
        <?php 
        foreach ( $taxterms as $term ) { 
            echo '<option value="'.$term->slug.'"'. selected($term->term_id,$current_term->term_id).'>'. $term->name . '</option>'; 
        } ?>
 </select>
```